# Cannot change owner of mounted drive

Tags: linux, filesystems, users

I have two users A and B on a remote ubuntu box (+ a bunch more). I now ssh to the machine with user A. Then I change to user B:

```
su B
```

and run

```
sudo mount -a
```

This mounts a windows fileshare that I specified in /etc/fstab:

```
//windowsshare/backup/tmp /media/backup/ cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode 0 0
```

Even though I mounted the drive as user B its user A that owns the folder:

```
B@ubuntu:/media$ ll
totalt 16
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root 4096 dec 27 12:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root 4096 jun  8  2012 ../
drwxr-xr-x  1 A root    0 dec 21 11:06 backup/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root 4096 jun  8  2012 cdrom/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root    7 jun  8  2012 floppy -> floppy0/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root 4096 jun  8  2012 floppy0/
```

I have tried to run (still as user B):

```
sudo chown -R B backup
```

But I still get the above picture = user A owns the backup folder. Why is it not possible to change owner on the above folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are *not* mounting the drive as either userA or userB. Since you are using `sudo` you are actually mounting the drive as `root`.

That said, it is owned by userA because you are specifically setting it to be so owned in your `fstab`:

> //windowsshare/backup/tmp /media/backup/ cifs guest,**uid=1000**,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode 0 0

`uid` stands for user ID. I guess that userA's UID is 1000 (you can check by running `id` as userA). Removing the `uid=1000` option from `fstab` should do what you need.

Comment: I changed uid=1001 which is user B's id (from cat /etc/passwd) and it now works.

Comment: Yes, but now it will be owned by user B. Is that what you want?

Comment: For now it should only be user B that is allowed to write to the specific folder. If I remove uid=1000 from fstab I need to change the write permissions manually right?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You can also set `umask` and `gid` options. You can also make the drive mountable by a normal user `users` and it will then  be owned by whoever mounts it. Have a look at `man fstab`.